# Shadow catcher for curved surface in EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

I'm using EEVEE as my main renderer and I need to provide a 2D team with a character image with a shadow in translucent pixels.

My character is standing on a curved floor. However, all of the EEVEE shadow catcher methods I found through Googling and YouTube search turned out to only work well on flat surfaces. The EEVEE shadow catcher method seemed to have a limitation of including the shadow of the floor itself when the floor has a slope or when a light other than the Sun type is installed.

Of course I can solve my problem by outputting shadow catcher pass using Cycles and combining them with EEVEE character pass in compositor. But I wonder if there is a shadow catcher method for curved floors in EEVEE as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in trouble too with shadow passes, different problems arise in cycles or eevee and both are useless.

I have finally created a different scene with a material overide with one white diffuse material applied. Not perfect but worked enough in my case ...